# Can "vorletzte oder letzte Seite" be shortened?

Tags: standard-german, formality

This is the original sentence:

> Dies finden Sie auf dem Resümeebogen (letzte Seite/n des
>   Gesprächsbogens).

I need to adjust it because now the résumé could also be on the second last page and an unrelated page could be the last - it depends on what is filled in previously.

So I would like to write

> Dies finden Sie auf dem Resümeebogen (vorletzte oder letzte Seite/n des
>   Gesprächsbogens).

But it is too long, can I also write `vor-/letzte Seite/n` or is it unclear/wrong and do you know a better way to shorten this?

Optional: also if the résumé would be more than 1 page long it would technically be incorrect to say last or second last page because it could start earlier. Not sure how to solve that issue.

Comment: What's wrong with "am Ende dieses Dokuments? Shouldn't be too hard to find...

Comment: That's the problem - it might be at the end, but it also might be the second last page with the last page being a completely different page. It depends on what is filled out before. The document has some programming in it that will make it show or hide a page at the end

Comment: Since the next to last page is obviously (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367902/negative-list-index) S. -2, you want S. -2f.

Comment: This is not a programming question though, the text in my question is not written inside that dynamic document and is not linked to it either. Just plain text.

Comment: Isn't the second-to-last page still towards the end? "am Ende" can mean both "at the end" and "towards the end"

Comment: Your requirements are too complicated to express reasonably with the term *Seite*. You should switch to another term, e.g. "vorletzter *Abschnitt* des Gesprächsbogens".

Comment: I was trying to be funny.

Comment: I second @tofro 's idea. "Am Ende" does not mean that it is the very last thing. In colloquial, you often hear "ziemlich am Ende" which clearly indicates that it is *not* the last thing. It's a pity that you cannot go with "ziemlich" in your case. Would sound a bit awkward.

Comment: @CarstenS Sorry, my bad :D - didn't get it

Comment: @Em1 - I also think that it's a pity that I can't go with "ziemlich" 'cause that would make it obvious enough to me, but "am Ende" sounds like the very last page when I first read it. - so I'm going with the answer posted here.
Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never thought about shortening this kind of expression before but I could give it a try.
First of all `vor-/letzte Seite/n` is not wrong but looks a little bit... meh.

You could try Something like this:

> (auf den letzten Seiten des Gesprächsbogens)

So it would look like this:

> Dies finden Sie auf dem Resümeebogen (auf den letzten Seiten des Gesprächsbogens).

this basically means: "on the last few pages".
But now it looks a little uncomfortable, or hard reading, since you have to read the same quote "auf dem" and "auf den" directly behind each other.

But we can fix it to look like that:

> Dies finden Sie in dem Resümeebogen (auf den letzten Seiten des Gesprächsbogens).

I hope I could help.

P.S. please correct me if i got anything wrong

Comment: take a look at my comment on the original question - there might be another unrelated page at the very end of the document. But `auf den letzten Seiten` doesn't necessarily include the very last page, right? Could it just mean `somewhere among the last pages`? I think then it is a good solution for me :)

Comment: Wäre ich der Leser, würde ich *auf den letzten Seiten* in der Tat als *irgendwo auf den letzen Seiten* verstehen, das heißt die allerletzte Seite, oder auch mehrere, müssen nicht unbedingt eingeschlossen sein. Kurz: Ja, du kannst das getrost so sagen.